# SQL Query not updating data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wrote a simple form from which a user will change his/her name , Facebook Name and image
here is the profile.php code with the form

```
 <!!--edit form--!!>

 <div id="edit">
 <table width="300" border="0"  align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1"   
 bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
 <tr>
 <td>
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
 <tr>
 <form method="POST" action="save_profile.php">
 <td colspan="3"><strong>Username<br><? echo $row['session'];?></strong></td>
 <td colspan="3"><strong>Name</strong><input type="text" name="name" id="name" 
 value="<?      echo $row['name'];?>"/><br></td>
 <td colspan="3"><strong>Facebook</strong><input type="text" name="fb" id="fb" value="<? echo $row['facebook'];?>"/></td>
 <td colspan="3"><strong>Image</strong><input type="text" name="img" id="img" value="<? echo $row['img'];?>"/></td>
 <input type="hidden" name="pros" />
 <input type="submit" value="Save" />
 </form>
```

and this is the save_profile.php

```
 <?
 include"sp-includes/sp-config2.php";
 $resultz = mysql_query($slctq);
 while($rowqw = mysql_fetch_array($resultz, MYSQL_ASSOC))
 {
 if($_POST['pros']){
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $fb=$_POST['fb'];
 $img=$_POST['img'];
 $do =mysql_query("UPDATE profile SET name='$name', facebook='$fb', img='$img' WHERE      id='$rowqw[id]'");
 }
 echo $rowqw['id'];
 }
 ?>
```

I dont Know where i am wrong..

Comment: What errors do you get? Any output?

Comment: $do = mysql_query("UPDATE profile SET name='" . $name . "' WHERE id='" . $rowqw[id] . "'");

Comment: What is your problem? If there is no error, try adding a line like `print mysql_error()` after the `$do = ...` line.

Comment: or try this :

$do = mysql_query("UPDATE profile SET name='{$name}' WHERE id='{$rowqw[id]}'");

Comment: also, try to include error checking after every operation by using mysql_error()

Comment: @SameerAnand Doesn't Work . still blank

Comment: Your database connection is fine? working or not??

Comment: @Learner yup its working fine

Comment: what is the value of $_POST['pros']... i believe it is blank,i.e. not set. make a check on `if(!isset($_POST['pros']))` and then try to update the table

Comment: Put your query in a separate variable and print that. `$query = "UPDATE profile SET name='$name', facebook='$fb', img='$img' WHERE      id='$rowqw[id]'; print $query;`. You should see the error from there then.

Comment: @SameerAnand its a hidden text field. after usingif(!isset($_POST['pros'])) it still doesnt does the query..

Comment: in that case, try updating without any conditions, if it works that way, try checking for `if($_POST['pros']=="")`

Comment: @SameerAnand I fixed it by putting the query out of the if{} condition... it worked, but is it ok?

Comment: for security purpose, try auto-generating the values for pros and then check against that auto-generated value!! otherwise it is fine

Comment: i'm glad that i could help you :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all, **PLEASE SANITIZE YOUR QUERIES**. Your query is completely open for exploitation right now and that might entirely be the reason why it fails.

Write your query like this:

```
mysql_query('UPDATE profile SET name="'.mysql_real_escape_string($name).'", facebook="'.mysql_real_escape_string($fb).'", img="'.mysql_real_escape_string($img).'" WHERE      id="'.mysql_real_escape_string($rowqw['id']).'";');
```

Also, note that the rowqw index should be written as 'id' instead of id.

Comment: Ya Thats True, I'm aware and was gonna do this later on.. But it didnt work even after this

Answer (score 2):

The problems with your code:

- You are not checking for errors. Use `mysql_error()`.
- You are not checking your input (if it's valid or not). You should be binding parameters or escaping with `mysql_real_escape_string`.
- Put the query in a separate string. Something like `$query = "UPDATE ..."; $do = mysql_query($query);`. It is useful for debugging. You know what the exact query you are sending is.
- You are using `$rowq[id]` the wrong way. When in a string you either use the `.` notation, you concatenate multiple strings; or you enclose it in `{$rowq[id]}`.

When you do all this, you'll solve the problems yourself. Read the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) too.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to
$do = mysql_query("UPDATE profile SET name = '$name', facebook = '$fb', img = '$img' WHERE id = '$rowqw[id]'");